# how do I round numbers with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, double, nsnumberformatter

I've got a calculation for example 57 / 30 so the solution will be 1,766666667..
How do i first of all get the 1,766666667 i only get 1 or 1.00 and then how do i round the solution (to be 2)?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

57/30 performs integer division. To obtain a float (or double) result you should make 1 of the operands a floating point value:

```
result = 57.0/30;
```

To round result have a look at standard `floor` and `ceil` functions.